# Any way to give alias for expression used in CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query below,

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) BETWEEN 0
                AND 20
            THEN '1'
        WHEN floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) BETWEEN 21
                AND 30
            THEN '2'
        WHEN floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) BETWEEN 31
                AND 40
            THEN '3'
        WHEN floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) BETWEEN 41
                AND 50
            THEN '4'
        ELSE '5'
        END ) Age_Band
FROM dual
```

Is there any way to give alias to the expression `floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12)` and use it in case statement like below.

```
CASE floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) **age**
        WHEN **age**  BETWEEN 0 AND 20  THEN '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if you use a subquery:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN z.flor BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN '1'
    WHEN z.flor BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '2'
    WHEN z.flor BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '3'
    WHEN z.flor BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '4'
    else '5' end Age_Band
FROM (SELECT floor(months_between
       (CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) flor
      From dual)z
```

but you could also do this:

```
 Select case when months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) > 60 then 5 
         else 1 + floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 240) end
 From dual
```

wouldn't that do the same thing?

Comment: Probably not. For one thing, that formula will never produce the result 0, which is desired when "age" is between 0 and 20. For another, the bands aren't even width - the first one is 20 years and the rest are 10 years.

Comment: ahhh yes, you're right. the approach could work, but the expression would have to be quite a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alias a CASE statement, however, sometimes to make things more readable and compact I use subquery for calculations.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN calc.date_value BETWEEN 0
                AND 20
            THEN '1'
        WHEN calc.date_value BETWEEN 21
                AND 30
            THEN '2'
        WHEN calc.date_value  BETWEEN 31
                AND 40
            THEN '3'
        WHEN calc.date_value  BETWEEN 41
                AND 50
            THEN '4'
        ELSE '5'
        END
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
    date_value=floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) 
 FROM 
    dual
)AS calc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE or a sub query. Here is a CTE since others have a sub-query:

```
WITH floor AS
(
   SELECT floor(months_between(CAL_DATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12) AS floor
   FROM dual
)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN f.floor BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN '1'
    WHEN f.floor BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '2'
    WHEN f.floor BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '3'
    WHEN f.floor BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '4'
    ELSE '5' END AS Age_Band
FROM floor f
```